# Design pattern for data flow

Tags: c#, design-patterns, selenium, automation, workflow

We have some kind of test-workflow consisting of steps.
Now I want to build classes to represent that.

e.g.

```
Step 1: Get edit control for username
Step 2: Write username into the control
Step 3: Get edit control for password
Step 4: Write password into the control
Step 5: Click Login Button
```

The problem is: How can i have those steps to easily exchange information?
How can i easily use the edit control of Step 1 in the code of Step 2?

At the moment I just have the following code:

```
public abstract class TestCase
{
    // the Steps to build the test
    public IList<TestStep> TestSteps { get; set; }

    public TestCase()
    {
        this.TestSteps = new List<TestStep>();
    }

    public abstract void Run();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }
}

public class TestStep
{
    public int StepNumber { get; set; } 
    public Func<bool> StepFunc { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get the Control in Step1, use it in Step2 and so on.

Thought of having different StepFunc's that have a return value suiting the needs
or a member in a specialized TestStep-derived class. But there is probably a 
better way.

**Please note:** At the moment I cannot do this in one step.

Any ideas highly appreciated!

Comment: Could it be necessary for Step X to need the results of Step Y *and* Step Z? For example, Step X needs both the control for username and that for password.

Comment: Sure, this can be necessary. Just gave a simple example to make it easier to talk about it.

Comment: Who should know where the parameters come from? Should Step X know that it needs to results from Step 1 and Step 3 (and not from 2 and 4) or should the controller know that? I am of the opinion that you need to somehow "hard"-code it, you can't automatically derive the correct step for all parameters.

Comment: BTW: Is there a specific reason why you are not using the Windows Workflow Foundation for this task? It has everything you need. Each TestStep could be implemented as an Activity class.

Comment: @Daniel: The reason is that I do not know the Workflow foundation that good. I do not see where it has those things that I need.

Comment: It has everything you need: You would use a StateMachine workflow, with each state being a TestStep which is implemented as an Activity. The Workflow is the controller that holds the results and passes them to the steps needed. I think that could be quite elegant.

Comment: Very nice idea! Actually it is a finite state machine of course. Will elaborate on that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Introduce a stepcontroller holds the steps to execute and that controls the execution of the steps, when it executes the step 2 it passes the result of step 1 to step 2. Step 2 should not have access to the edit control of step 1 but rather acess to the result of step 1, which is the text entered into the edit control of step 1.
Of course the result of the steps can also be accumulated so that result of step 4 contains both the username and the password.

Comment: Thank you! The `TestCase` is something like a stepcontroller. But I have no information at the moment which Step needs which information (not externally modelled right now).

Comment: Can't you accumulate all information in one result for each test case. Or: Each test step of a test case acts on a common shared data, wich is the SUT. All steps know the SUT.

Comment: SUT like Structure Under Test? Seems like a very good idea! Some steps build the structure and some use it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. All steps need to to know the SUT because the act upon the SUT.